# How to call autowired service from JUnit test method

Tags: java, spring, junit

I have a spring MVC small application and I need to integrate a test method using JUnit testing.

The class model I have is `Page`:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Entity
@Table(name="page")
public class Page  implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "about")
    private String about;

    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    // the rest of getters and setters...
}
```

Also, I have a service which calls the PageDAO interface to connect to DB and get the data:

```
@Service
public class PageServiceImpl implements PageService {

    @Autowired
    private PageDAO pageDao;

    public void saveOrUpdatePage(Page page) {
        pageDao.saveOrUpdate(page);
    }

    public Page getPage(int id) {
        Page page = pageDao.get(id);
        return page;
    }
}
```

`PageDAOImpl`:

```
@Repository("pageDAO")
public class PageDAOImpl implements PageDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Transactional
    public void saveOrUpdate(Page page) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(page);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Page get(int id) {
        String hql = "from Page where id=" + id;
        Query query = this.sessionFactory.openSession().createQuery(hql);

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Page> listPage = (List<Page>) query.list();

        if (listPage != null && !listPage.isEmpty()) {
             return listPage.get(0);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And finally, I have the test class `PageControllerTest`:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration("web.xml")
@ContextConfiguration
public class PageControllerTest {

    @Test
    public void testGetPageInfo() {
        Page expectedPage = new Page();
        expectedPage.setName("Pivotal");
        Page actualPage = new Page();
        // I need here to get a Page from the database using PageService `get` method passing 1 as page ID for parameter.
        assertEquals(expectedPage.getName(), actualPage.getName());
    }
}
```

How can I call the autowired PageService in order to get the page from db and compare it with the `expectedPage` name property?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this annotation to the test class,

```
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:your-spring-beans-config-file-path.xml")
```

Autowire the service to @test class,

```
@Autowired
PageService pageService;
```

Comment: yes ok but the question is how can I call the get method in PageService?

Answer (score 0):

You can inject dependencies in your test class, as you would in any controller, service or DAO class:

```
@Autowired
private PageService pageService;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called [EasyMock](http://easymock.org/).It provides a good and easy to integrate framework to write unit tests in a web application.

You know before hand what id's of the page might be(as part of your test data) and mock rest of the data in the model.